# Eclipse not found Existing web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, web

I Have existing web app Project. I followed following steps to import the existing project 
import->Existing project into workspace->folder . but it showing **no project are found to import**. Here I'm also attaching screen shots which I proceeded.

first:
[image: first]

---

second:
[image: second]

I'm not able to figure out the error. could you please help me

Comment: don't select the `src` folder, select the root folder `life`

Comment: @Pau I selected root folder life but still same error

Comment: @SUBBUBANDAM is the folder Life an eclipse project?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee Note that your link is talking about Importing a Project to Eclipse From *an Archive File*. It's not what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 3):

In order for a folder to be a valid *Eclipse project* folder, it should contain `.project` `.settings` and `.classpath` files.

You should choose the folder that **contains** these files.

Comment: This is a web project @SHG

Comment: @SUBBUBANDAM These 3 files will exist in a web project as well. The thing that web project has in addition to the files I mentioned, is `WebContent` folder.

Comment: @SUBBUBANDAM Did you originally create this project using Eclipse?

Comment: yeah I created using eclipse only.

Comment: @SUBBUBANDAM Well, you can try to find it by running in Windows cmd in the topmost folder of your project `dir /s /b` (it will output the folder contents recursively) and search these files in the results.

Comment: @SUBBUBANDAM Verify that hidden files are displayed.